# Does Google Earth Builder support server-side geoprocessing?

Tags: geoprocessing

Is there a feature in [Google Earth Builder](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/builder.html) that supports server-side geoprocessing?

For example, say I upload two large geo datasets to Google's cloud: one with lots of points and another with lots of polylines.

Is there some way I can write a script and upload it to the cloud that:

1. finds all points in dataset1 within
   some distance of a line in dataset2
   having some attribute = some
   specified value.
2. find all points within some distance
   of the points from step 1 where some
   attribute = some value
3. buffer the points from 2 based on
   some other attribute, and return the
   results

I would like for this script to run on the server - not on the client.

**Update**: I watched most of the [webinar at Directions Magazine](http://www.directionsmag.com/webinars/view/exploring-google-earth-builder-with-the-product-team/175790), last week.  The  <del>first 3/4's of the</del> webinar, which included the entire demo and didn't address this question.   <del>Right now it is in the process of being archived, but should be available for viewing again shortly</del>.

**Update**  The webinar archive is now available for viewing.

Comment: I'm sure we're going to start seeing a lot of Google Earth Builder questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do Spatial Queries with Google Earth Builder and Fusion Tables

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM 297050 WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(Address, RECTANGLE(LATLNG(37.2, -122.3), LATLNG(37.6, -121.9)))
```

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/11/search-your-geo-data-using-spatial.html

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/
is a good starting resource

As for the server-sided geoprocessing - it  is unclear - seems like google want to use their servers for this.

Comment: A google rep told me the same thing.  Still, this means pulling massive amounts of data onto the client, essentially doing the join client-side.  If/when google supports this on the server side things will get interesting.